# What does "crime presents a concern for citizens" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does "crime presents a concern for citizens" mean citizens find crime problematic in their city and they show concern for it?

Answer (score 2):

***[Concern](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01PgXfdncAw_g5gfGdyeRXmmpx5-g%3A1609344589758&source=hp&ei=TabsX83RK8OSlwTF5pfgBA&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX-y0XZ1i4AK1horIuuCMjyzgY9PyEslS&q=concern&oq=concern&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQsQMQyQMyBQgAELEDMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQMyBQgAELEDMggILhDHARCvATIICC4QsQMQgwEyAggAMgUIABCxAzICCAA6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOggIABCxAxCDAToOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6CwgAELEDEIMBEJECOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoFCC4QsQM6DQgAEMkDEJECEEYQ-QE6DgguEMcBEK8BEMkDEJMCULQNWKcdYPkhaABwAHgAgAFniAGeBZIBAzQuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiNrN3ki_btAhVDyYUKHUXzBUwQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)*** here means worry, anxiety.

> Crime presents a concern/***is a matter of concern*** for citizens.

This means crime exists in their environment and they are worried because of the danger it presents. It is not something to be ignored.